# Why do I get an exception in my code when entering the first value?

Tags: java, eclipse

So when my code is ran I get this error once I try to enter the first value.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at Exercise_5.main(Exercise_5.java:30)
```

Here is the code and the error appears at line 30 at `ls[i][j] = tempString.charAt(0);`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise_5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter number n:");
        n = input.nextInt();

        char[][] ls = new char[n][n];
        String tempString = "";

        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the letter for " + i + "," + j);
                tempString = input.nextLine();
                if(tempString.length() > 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                }
                else
                {
                    ls[i][j] = tempString.charAt(0);
                }
            }
        }

        boolean latinSquare = true;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n && latinSquare ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < n && latinSquare ; j++)
            {
                char element = ls[i][j];
                for(int k = j + 1 ; k < n && latinSquare ; k++)
                {
                    if(ls[i][j] == element)
                    {
                        latinSquare = false;
                    }
                }
                for(int k = i + 1 ; k < n && latinSquare ; k++)
                {
                    if(ls[i][j] == element)
                    {
                        latinSquare = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(latinSquare)
        {
            System.out.println("The square is a latin square");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The square is not a latin square");
        }
    }

}
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why it happens.

Comment: The string must be empty.

Comment: Anyone asking a question here is in need of assistance. Putting it in the question title, in capital letters no less, will not make people want to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = input.nextInt();
```

Here [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) will only consume the `int` value and *skips* the new line character.

```
tempString = input.nextLine();
```

Here, `tempString` will consume the new line character. So when you get to this line:

```
ls[i][j] = tempString.charAt(0);
```

You'll be getting this exception.

Try to add another `nextLine` *before* you actually read the String from the user so it'll consume the new line character.

Furthermore, your validation makes no sense, as you're checking if the length is bigger than zero, and if not, you try to access the character at the 0's place, which doesn't exist.